# How to find a matrix to multiply in order to get the eigenvalues?

Tags: matrices

I have a symmetric $k$ by $k$ matrix **B** with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\dots \lambda_k$. I found a result in an old linear models book that says "there exists an orthogonal matrix **Q** such that **Q'BQ**= **D**" where **D** = diag($\lambda_1,\dots \lambda_k$).

My question is whether or not there is a more efficient way to determine **Q** than to solve the entire set of equations?

**UPDATE**

In the simplest case, **B**$=-\frac{\theta^2}{4+2\theta^2}\cdot$
 \begin{pmatrix} 5+5\theta^2+\theta^4 & \sqrt{1+\theta^2} \\ \sqrt{1+\theta^2} & 1\end{pmatrix}

Comment: You don't need to open old books to find [this result](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix#Decomposition).

Comment: Do you want to solve the system by hand? What is k? Give us B.

Comment: @wok, I was following a different result in the old book, but thanks for the reference.  I'd prefer not to solve the system by hand if possible. I have added the simplest case of B above

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Find the eigenspaces, and arbitrarily take an orthonormal basis in each. These will form the columns of $Q$.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you are looking at the spectral decomposition of $B=QDQ^{'}$. So what yo have to do is find the eigen vectors of the matrix $B$. Their exist many efficient numerical algorithms to do that. The two popular ones are

- QR algorithm,
  Read about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_algorithm)
- Divide and Conquer Algorithm,
  Read about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_eigenvalue_algorithm)